# Role wise editing and deleting the permissions on a node in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a drupal7 site and I need to implement this functionality into the site. I have two user roles(private and public), if a user of public role creates a node then all the users of public role should be given the edit and delete permissions for that node but the users of the private role should only be able to view the node and vice-versa. Please tell me how to achieve this pro grammatically as I have been searching for a module that can perform this functionality and there is no such module.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought.

2 content types: public_node & private_node. 
Then use module Content Access: http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: I cannot have two content types since there are api's which deliver information two other applications and if i change it two different content types then the whole api needs to be re-written